# Clear certain cells with X style

Tags: excel, vba

I select a sheet and `ClearContents` anything that has a particular style.

The code is crashing.

Expected to delete anything in a given style.

```vb
Sub Reset_User_Inputs()

    Dim input_cell As Range
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    
    Sheet1.Cells.Select
    
    For Each input_cell In Selection
        If input_cell.Style = "RESETABLE" Then
            input_cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next input_cell
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Clear Cells With a Certain Style

```vb
Sub ResetUserInputs()
    
    ' Combine the critical cells into a range.
     
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheet1.UsedRange
    
        For Each cell In .Cells
            If cell.Style = "RESETABLE" Then
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = cell
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    
    End With

    ' Clear the range in one go.
    
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then
        urg.ClearContents
    End If

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "User inputs reset.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting the whole sheet and then iterate over all cells ... that's too much, I suppose.

You neither need to select nor need to check the whole sheet.
If you use `UsedRange` it won't crash.

```vb
Public Sub reset_user_inputs(ws As Worksheet, styleName As String)

Dim c As Range
For Each c In ws.UsedRange
    If c.Style = styleName Then c.ClearContents
Next

End Sub
```

You can call this sub like this: `reset_user_inputs Sheet1, "RESETABLE"`

You can use this generic routine for any worksheet and for any style :-)

Comment: Thanks so much! Will give this a try when I get home but that was one of my suspicions. Hoping it works (and I don't have some other issue with excel on my home computer!)